# How to count a column plus one on ORM Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I'm having some problem with Kohana and ORM.

I want to update a

```
column = column + 1
```

that it! as simple as that.

I tried in many ways and always duplicate the count, for example:

```
initial column value = 0
column = column + 1
result = 3 (how is this possible???)
```

These are the ways and nothing is working...

this are the many tries and nothing works :(

```
public function update_views()
{
    $this->set('column', DB::expr('column + 1'))->save();
}
public function update_views()
{
    $this->set('column', $this->column + 1)->update();
}

public function update_views()
{
    DB::update('table')->set(array('column' => DB::expr('column + 1')))->where('id', '=', $this->id)->execute(); // this was my last hope and nothing.... 
}
```

All three working perfectly, no errors, no nothing... just when i checked the table on the DB is not what I want... Any suggestions? please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code should work, the bug must be somewhere else

Comment: check `Database::instance()->last_query` value

Answer (score 0):

I think it is probably because you are trying to call update afterwards instead of save. I am not sure why this would cause it to not actually updated but the following code should work.

```
public function update_views()
{
    $this->column = $this->column + 1;
    $this->save();
}
```

Comment: paquettg Thank you, but doesn't work either :(
@biakaveron it's increment the views one by one, but in view source mode when i refresh (F5), in the page itself not.

But, when I open the page itself, increment it's value, sometimes 2 or 3 times more than 1 (like the last query).  How do you explain that? I'm not an expert in ORM, but, for every time that page load update many times this same thing?  like if I'm invoking many times the same function.  How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

DB::update('tablname')->set(array('column_name' => DB::expr('column_name + 1'))->where('id', '=', 'primary_key')->execute();

worked for me.